# Git - After creating a branch from master I have to sync with master to get its source. Why?

Tags: merge

I'm finding that after creating a branch from master that the new branch doesn't have the same source code as master. Ultimately I have to sync after creating the branch to make it work.  Why is that?  The steps below show what I'm doing, or I made a movie of this: https://youtu.be/m0rhpG6Skac

1) In Bitbucket (on the website) I create a new branch (BranchB) from master.

2) I fetch and then checkout BranchB locally

3) I create a text file called BranchB.txt and save it.

4) I use git status to verify that git sees the untracked file

5) I add the file, make a commit, and then push the branch to remote

6) I verify in BitBucket that the branch was just updated and then merge with the master branch (presumably master has branchB.txt at this point)

7) I create a new branch from master called BranchC using Bitbucket website

8) I fetch and checkout BranchC locally verifying that I am on that new branch

9) **I find that BranchB.txt is NOT THERE.  Why is that???**

10) On the BitBucket website, I find that BranchC is two commits behind master. 
**Why??**

11) I sync BranchC with master (a step I wouldn't have thought necessary)

12) I verify that BranchB.txt now exists in BranchC on remote

13) locally I do a git pull and verify that BranchB.txt exists.

Comment: Can't reproduce. There's nothing about what you did in the video that would cause _branchB.txt_ to disappear from the workspace, and indeed when I try it, it doesn't disappear. Is there something you did that you didn't show us? I can readily see how this would happen. however, if you first switched to a branch that lacks _branchB.txt_ before fetching the remote `BranchC`. Did you do that but hide it from us by cutting it out of the video?

Comment: No - I did do some editing, but only to remove delays while waiting for merges...I was on BranchB (which of course has branchB.txt) when I did the fetch. At 2:37 into the video, you  can actually see in the command window what I've typed and that branch.txt was present in BranchB. At that point I do a git fetch, and mysteriously the file is gone.  I have to say it "feels' like the merge of BranchB wasn't really completed at the time that I created BranchC. Clearly the notification popped up saying it had merged though (you can see that at 2:04 in the video).  https://youtu.be/m0rhpG6Skac?t=155

Comment: Yes, what you describe (_BranchB.txt_ disappears, Branch C on BitBucket is two commits behind master) is sort of what I would expect if you had branched BranchC off from a commit on master from _before_ the BranchB merge commit. But in that case this would all be some sort of issue on the BitBucket site; it wouldn't really be a git matter at all, would it?